# Stochastic process markov chain probability feature

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, markov-chains, markov-process

I could not understant the reason of following equality?
How did they write as difference of two random variables?

[image]

Comment: For every random variables $X$ and $Y$, $$P(X=x\mid Y=y)=P(X-Y=x-y\mid Y=y)$$ since $$\{X=x\}\cap\{Y=y\}=\{X-Y=x-y\}\cap\{Y=y\}$$ Furthermore, *if $X-Y$ and $Y$ are independent, $$P(X-Y=x-y\mid Y=y)=P(X-Y=x-y)$$ Thus, in your case, everything reduces to the remark that $T_{n+1}-T_n$ is independent of $T_n$.

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $T_n$ is the time of $n$th success. The time to the $(n+1)$th success is equal to the time to $n$th success, plus a random number $K$.

Let $j-i=k$. Then
$$T_{n+1}=T_n+k$$ 
This can be written as $$T_{n+1}-T_n=k=j-i$$

It follows that $K\sim \tt Geometric(p)$  whose pdf is $$f_K(k)=p(1-p)^{k-1},\,k\in\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$$

Comment: How does this address the OP's concern?